# Выбор программ и языка для создания контента

Tags: java, клиент

Здравствуйте, 
У меня появился вопрос. Я попыталась найти в гуугле ответ, но нашла какие-то общие мысли и ничего конкретного.

Меня как начинающего программиста заинтересовало как можно создать (какие языки программирования и какие библиотеки использовать) веб сайт, который будет предоставлять услуги клиентам для создания их собственного графического контента.

Вот примеры таких сайтов. Я как обычный пользователь могу создать свой сайт с определенным дизайном и отредактировать фотографию, использую разные фильмы и разную функциональность.
https://www.wix.com
https://avatan.ru/#/
Я знаю, что это все популярная и известная тема, но меня за мои годы обучения в университете ни разу не сталкивали с такими рода проблемами. 
(Мы программировали какие-то онлайн магазины, библиотеки, кинотеатры, а до таких вещей дело не доходило)
Если я, например, являюсь фанатом java и планирую изучить react js - возможно ли создать что-то подобное в целях самообразования, используя эти языки? 
И есть ли каки-нибудь научные статьи на эти темы (может быть примеры имплементации на GitHub) или еще лучше - книги, которые могут послужить для меня альма матром при изучении данного вопроса.

Заранее спасибо за ответ и ваши комментарии!

Comment: `создать веб сайт, который будет предоставлять услуги клиентам для создания их собственного графического контента` - какой графический контент вы подразумеваете?

Comment: я привела пример ссылок. не хочу зацикливаться на определенном чем-то. но в идеале должно быть так, чтобы пользователь мог передвигать разные компоненты, тексты, менять дизайн страницы (не просто перегружать фон, а разные фильтры может применять) и все это просто в web

Comment: Так вам нужен такой же редактор, по типу викс, но чтобы в результате была картинка? То  есть не фотошоп (сложный редактор), а чтобы можно было картинку в конструкторе сделать, наложив готовые элементы из предоставленного вами ассортимента?

Comment: именно. начать хочу с такого формата. фотошоп будет уже следующем уровнем

Comment: @Julia На клиенте у вас будет так или иначе JavaScript, HTML5, Canvas и/или SVG. Серверная часть может быть хоть на Java, хоть на любом другом языке общего назначения, на котором можно создать web-сервер. *Если я, например, являюсь фанатом java и планирую изучить react js* - React это про JavaScript, а не про Java, но никто не мешает вам использовать java на сервере.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите на существующие библиотеки JavaScript для работы с графикой: [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/showcase/), [Raphaël](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/), [Fabric.js.](http://fabricjs.com/).

Comment: Научные статьи тут вам не нужны, это совершенно инженерная задача.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо большое! Еще такой вопрос: предположим я использую все эти компоненты, которые можно передвигать в разные стороны на javascript с определенными библиотеками. для них сервер нужен ведь только для того чтобы сохранить то, что получилось у юзера. Чтобы это сохранить, нужно ли создавать переменные таких же компонентов на java?

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы разделите функциональность между клиентом и сервером. В минимальном варианте серверной стороны, клиент отправляет на сервер в каком-то виде состояние редактируемого контента (xml, json, ваш собственный бинарный формат), хранит его и умеет отдавать обратно. Если же минимизировать клиент, то на сервер отправляются операции ("сдвинуть контур 1 вправо на 10 px"), и он хранит все промежуточные состояния в своих структурах данных.

Comment: Скорее всего вы захотите какой-то промежуточный вариант. Тут надо исходить из постановки задачи. Например, однопользовательский редактор будет ближе к первому варианту, поддерживающий одновременную работу нескольких пользователей над одним материалом - ближе ко второму варианту. Также не забывайте, что сервер будет заниматься инфраструктурой вокруг основной задачи: пользователи, сессии, проекты.

Comment: Спасибо! Это все понимаю. Хочется конечно второй вариант. Поэтому сделаю упор на сервис. Спасибо еще раз!